# Explanation of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test with applications in Java

Tags: distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, java

I'm trying to apply the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for goodness-of-fit to a dataset. I have a large set of values, and would like to know whether it fits a Poisson distribution with given $\lambda$.

As I am using Java to generate the dataset, I have found a Java class which is supposed to calculate what I want - it's called [jsc.goodnessfit.KolmogorovTest](http://www.jsc.nildram.co.uk/api/jsc/goodnessfit/KolmogorovTest.html).

There are three methods, `approxUpperTailProb(int n,double D)`, `exactUpperTailProb(int n,double D)`, and `getSP()`.

Did I understand correctly that `approxUpperTailProb()` calculates the approximate probability that my data fits the given distribution?

Also, the value `n` is the size of the sample set, but what is `D`? It's described as "the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic; must not be $< 0$ or $> 1$."
As far as I understand, it's the maximum distance of any point from my dataset to the corresponding point in the distribution I am comparing with. However, as I am comparing to a general Poisson distribution, I don't know how to calculate `D`.

Finally, what is `getSP()`? The documentation states that it "Returns the value of the significance probability." What does that mean?

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: K-S is for continuous distributions.  The Poisson is discrete.  Instead, estimate its parameter, use that to compute the probabilities, and conduct a [chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-square_test#Other_distributions).

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ABC
{
 public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    System.out.println("Enter Count of numbers:");
    n=s.nextInt();
    double d[]=new double[n];
    double dp[]=new double[n];
    double dm[]=new double[n];
    double dplus,dmin,dmax;
    System.out.println("Enter "+n+"Numbers:");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
         d[i]=s.nextDouble();
     }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(d[i]>d[j])
            {
                 double temp=d[i];
                 d[i]=d[j];
                 d[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        dp[i]=((double)(i+1)/n)-d[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        dm[i]=d[i]-((double)i/n);
    }
    System.out.println("i\tRi\t(i/N-Ri)\tRi-(i-1/N)");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println((i+1)+"\t"+d[i]+"\t"+dp[i]+"\t"+dm[i]);
        }
    dplus=dp[0];
    dmin=dm[0];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(dp[i]>dplus)
        {
            dplus=dp[i];
        }
    }

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(dm[i]>dmin)
        {
             dmin=dm[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("D+="+dplus+"\nD-="+dmin);

    double D=Math.max(dplus,dmin);

    System.out.println("D="+D);

    System.out.println("Enter the critical value:");
    double da=s.nextDouble();

    if(D>da)
    {
        System.out.println("Hypothesis H0 is Rejected");
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("Hypothesis H0 is Accepted");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated. Thank you for your answer. Can you add some explanation to your code?

Comment: I can't understand why you would want to spend time doing statistical calculations in Java when R and python have a wealth of carefully checked functions for these things.